# Set date/time value in H2 with PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I cannot figure out what the problem is. Nothing done here different from any other database, but while trying to use H2 (v1.3.176) is simply no luck. The table is:

```
CREATE TABLE AccessesByMinute (
  Count INT NOT NULL,
  UrlID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  ServerID BIGINT NOT NULL,
  RemoteIP VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Longitude FLOAT,
  Latitude FLOAT,
  Moment DATETIME,
  UserID DATETIME
);
```

The code is:

```
...
Date timestamp = Utils.getNearest(Calendar.MINUTE, access.getTimestamp());
...
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(time);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
....

     try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO AccessesByMinute (Moment, UserID, UrlID, ServerID, RemoteIP, Longitude, Latitude, Count) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1)");
      {
        ps.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(timestamp.getTime()));
        ps.setLong(2, userId);
        ps.setLong(3, urlId);
        ps.setLong(4, serverId);
        ps.setString(5, access.getRemoteIp());
        ps.setFloat(6, (loc == null ? 0 : loc.longitude));
        ps.setFloat(7, (loc == null ? 0 : loc.latitude));
        ps.executeUpdate();  
      }
```

And keep getting the error:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "1";
>   SQL statement:

timestamp.getTime() returns a long which is argument of java.sql.Timestamp
What am I not seeing?

Comment: Provide more code, specially about your `timestamp` variable.

Comment: Modified the question

Comment: You have `UserId` declared as `DATETIME`, I assume that should be `INT` or `BIGINT` instead. My guess is that you that the value of variable `userId` is 1.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You should add that as an answer. I can reproduce the problem, and changing `UserId` to `int` fixes it.

Comment: @ThomasMueller I could have done that, instead I voted to close as off-topic as I don't think it will be helpful for future visitors. However you - as developer of H2 - might want to consider throwing an explicit exception for unsupported combinations (eg `setLong` not supported for timestamp), you might also want to look at appendix B of the JDBC 4.2 spec for required/allowed combinations.

Comment: Well that is my own fault... much appreciated/embarrassed.